# ordering numpy by one column and then another (as a subset) whilst preserving row order

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, sorting

I have a numpy array -

```
 a = np.array([[1,23],[5,4],[56,12], [7,29], [3,4], [2,15],[2,8], [4,8]])
```

and wish to order it by column 1 and then by column 0 whilst preserving row order. I've managed to order it by axis 1 -

```
 a = a[a[:,1].argsort()]

 array([[ 5,  4],
   [ 3,  4],
   [ 4,  8],
   [ 2,  8],
   [56, 12],
   [ 2, 15],
   [ 1, 23],
   [ 7, 29]])
```

but column 0 also needs to be in ascending order within the ascending order of column 1, e.g:

```
array([[ 3,  4],
   [ 5,  4],
   [ 2,  8],
   [ 4,  8],
   [56, 12],
   [ 2, 15],
   [ 1, 23],
   [ 7, 29]])
```

How can this be achieved?

Comment: Look into lexsort.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `sorted` with multiple keys:

```
a = np.array([[1,23],[5,4],[56,12], [7,29], [3,4], [2,15],[2,8], [4,8]])

>>> np.array(sorted(a, key=lambda x: (x[1], x[0]))) # sort col 1 then col 0.
array([[ 3,  4],
       [ 5,  4],
       [ 2,  8],
       [ 4,  8],
       [56, 12],
       [ 2, 15],
       [ 1, 23],
       [ 7, 29]])
```